# constructors with argument in javascript

Tags: javascript

guys i know it is dummy question but i tried a lot and never reached .. here is my code 
in jsp

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadDepartment();" id="dep">Departments</button>
function loadDepartment(){
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url : '/Spring3HibernateApp1/indexDep',
                type : 'GET',
                error : function(that, e) {
                    alert(e);
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    var newData = data.MyListDep;
                    gridDep = new GridLibraryDep({data: newData});
                    gridDep.display();

                }
            });
        });
        }
```

and this in my JS

```js
function GridLibrary(data) {

  this.data = data;
  this.columns = $.map(this.data[0], function(item, key) {
   return key;
  });

  this.pageSize = 5;
  this.endIndex = startIndex + this.pageSize;
  document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = 1;
  document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = this.pageSize;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data.length;
  $("#first").click(bindContext(this.first, this));

 }
GridLibrary.prototype = {
  first : function() {
   var size = this.data.length;
   page = 1;
   // document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = page;
   this.endIndex = page * this.pageSize;
   startIndex = this.endIndex - this.pageSize;
   this.deleteTable();
   document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = 1;
   document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = this.endIndex;
   document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = size;
   this.display();
  }}
```

so my question is how to update the JS file to be called by jsp in that way (data: newData) ???

Comment: JSP has nothing whatsoever to do with JavaScript, I've removed the tag for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you call the constructor using

```
new GridLibraryDep({data: newData});
```

Then, within that constructor you should use

```
function GridLibrary(data) {
    this.data = data.data;
    ...
}
```

To obtain the values of `newData`

Comment: what if i want to pass data: newData, deletefunction: deleteDep(id); ??